# Where to ask a question about how to accomplish a specific task?

Tags: discussion

As the question states, I'd like to know where to ask for ideas on how to accomplish specific tasks. I know Code Review is for code that works, but you're looking for improvement. and StackOverflow is for code that doesn't work. But where can I ask about code I haven't written, but need ideas on how to accomplish?

Comment: This right here is evidence that Stack Overflow has essentially devolved into nothing more than a debug-my-code site as far as the average user is concerned.

Comment: What does Programmers SE say to you?

Comment: @random: Programmers is a site about whiteboards. Nothing to do with code. Unless one codes on a whiteboard. Or codes whiteboards. Which isn't all that far-fetched now that I think about it.

Comment: @BoltClock [not so far fetched indeed](https://www.google.com/search?q=smartborad&oq=smartborad&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1601j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=smartboard&spell=1)

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to have breaking code yet in order to post on stack overflow.  In fact, the best questions her don't have that.

You just need to know very specifically what you want.

here's a simple example:

> I have a string in language X that I need to convert to an int.  Are there any built in functions that do that for me?

That question does not contain any code, or any evidence of code, but It doesn't need to.  You're asking about how to accomplish a specific need.

**If the answer is not otherwise readily available**, that's **Exactly** the class of question that we're looking for(although normally the questions aren't as simple).

The one issue that you might run into is if the answer to that question is easy to answer by basic research, so try to do some of your own research first before you ask.

Comment: "That question does not contain any code, or any evidence of code, but It doesn't need to." The WHYT brigade would like to have a word with you.

Comment: @BoltClock I've always hated the WHYT brigade anyways

Comment: WHYT really depends on the size of the question.  If you have a 1-3 line answer, WHYT isn't applicable.  If you have something that requires a dozen lines of code, then I expect you to have tried something. Especially since 90% of the time a very quick google would get them 90-100% of the way there.

Comment: @GabeSechan  The important thing is that you make sure that answers get proper context of your question.  Showing what you've tried is just one of the ways that you can accomplish that.